How to properly integrate FastAPI server with react?
I have a FastAPI server, on post requests the user token is stored in cookies. I also have a telegram bot written in aiogram.
My idea is that in aiogram I send requests to the server, there the user data will be written to the database by the decrypted token, and in react I get this data by the user token to insert certain values into the template. For this I use cookie storage in the session. The queries in aiogram work correctly, everything is stored in the database, the token is decrypted, but in my react application I get a 403 Forbidden error:

127.0.0.1:8000/generation/api/data/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) RedSide1.tsx:46
Ошибка от сервера: Object config : {transitional: {…}, adapter:
Array(3), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1),
timeout: 0, …} data : {detail: 'Токен не найден в куки.'} headers :
AxiosHeaders {content-length: '54', content-type: 'application/json'}
request : XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4,
timeout: 0, withCredentials: true, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status : 403 statusText : "Forbidden" [[Prototype]] : Object)`)

Can you please tell me what is the cause of the error?
fast_api_server/src/some_feature/router.py
from auth.jwt_handler import sign_jwt, decode_jwt
from auth.auth_bearer import JWTBearer

router = APIRouter(
    prefix='/generation',
    tags = ['ImageGeneration'] 
)

####### POST REQUESTS #######

@router.post("/generate_token/")
async def generate_token(user: UserIDSchema, response: Response):
    
    token = await sign_jwt(user_id=user.user_id)
    # Установка токена в HTTP-only cookie
    response.set_cookie(
            key="access_token", 
            value=token['access_token'],
            httponly=True,  
            secure=False,   
            samesite="Lax"  
        )
    
    return {
        "status": "200",
        "data": token,
        "details": "Token is set in cookies"
    }

@router.post('/api/add_data', dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())])
async def create_user_details_for_second_template(
    new_template_info: Template2Param,
    request: Request,  # Получаем объект запроса для работы с куки
    session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)
):
    try:
        # Извлекаем токен из куки
        token = request.cookies.get("access_token")
        print(token)
        if not token:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Токен не найден в куки.")
        
        # Декодируем токен для получения user_id
        decoded_token = decode_jwt(token)
        if not decoded_token:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Невалидный или истекший токен.")

        user_id = decoded_token['user_id']

        # Вставляем данные с user_id
        stmt = insert(GenerationRequest).values(user_id=user_id, **new_template_info.model_dump())
        await session.execute(stmt)
        await session.commit()

        return {
            "status": "200",
            "data": new_template_info,
            "details": "All went correct and all data have been added"
        }
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"Ошибка: {str(e)}")


# Получаем данные из бд для второго шаблона
@router.get('/api/data', dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())])
async def get_all_data_for_second_template(request: Request, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
    try:
        # Извлекаем токен из куки
        token = request.cookies.get("access_token")
        if not token:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Токен не найден в куки.")
        
        # Декодируем токен для получения user_id
        decoded_token = decode_jwt(token)
        if not decoded_token:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Невалидный или истекший токен.")
        
        user_id = decoded_token['user_id']

        # Делаем запрос в базу данных с использованием user_id
        query = select(GenerationRequestAll).where(GenerationRequestAll.user_id == user_id).order_by(GenerationRequestAll.id.desc()).limit(1)
        result = await session.execute(query)

        last_record = result.scalar_one_or_none()

        if last_record:
            return {
                "status": "200",
                "data": last_record,
                "details": "Last record fetched successfully"
            }
        else:
            return {
                "status": "404",
                "data": None,
                "details": "No records found for the user"
            }
    except Exception as e:

        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"Error: {str(e)}")

tg_bot/some/some_handlers.py
# other code #

@staticmethod
    async def generate_unic_token(tg_id: int, client: httpx.AsyncClient) -> None:
        url_token = "link to post"
        response = await client.post(url_token, json={"user_id": tg_id})

        # Проверка ответа
        if response.status_code == 200:
            token_data = response.json()
            print("Токен успешно получен:", token_data)
        else:
            print("Ошибка при получении токена:", response.status_code, response.text)

    @staticmethod
    async def post_request_to_api(data_dict, api_url, telegram_id, message: Message) -> None:
        # Общие данные для отправки
        data_for_server = {
            "some_data":"some_data"
        }

        # Добавляем специфическое поле для 'all' типа
        if 'all' in api_url:
            data_for_server['restroom'] = data_dict['санузлы']
        else:
            data_for_server["ceiling"] = int(data_dict['потолок'])

        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            # Получаем токен и сохраняем куки в сессии
            cookies = httpx.Cookies()  # Создаем объект для хранения куки
            client.cookies = cookies  # Привязываем куки к клиенту
            
            # Получаем токен и сохраняем его в куки
            await Status.generate_unic_token(tg_id=telegram_id, client=client)

            # Используем ту же сессию для отправки данных
            response = await client.post(api_url, json=data_for_server)

            # Проверка ответа
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print("Данные успешно добавлены:", response.json())
            else:
                print("Ошибка при добавлении данных:", response.status_code, response.text)

            # Теперь делаем GET запрос, используя ту же сессию и куки
            response = await client.get('link to get to check')

            # Проверка ответа
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print("Данные успешно получены:", response.json())
            else:
                print("Ошибка при получении данных:", response.status_code, response.text)

    # отправляет запрос на добавление на сервер
    @router.message(State_Status.create_template)
    async def handle_post_request(message: Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
        data = await state.get_data()

        if data['choosing_template'] == 'Второй_шаблон':
            api_url = "link to post"
        else:
            api_url = "link to post"

        await Status.post_request_to_api(data_dict=data, api_url=api_url, telegram_id=message.from_user.id, message=message)

        await state.clear()
        
        

 frontend/src/pages/template.tsx


import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import FrameComponent1 from "../components/FrameComponent1";
import FrameComponent2 from "../components/FrameComponent2";
import Button1 from "../components/Button1";
import styles from "./RedSide1.module.css";


// Определяем интерфейс данных шаблона
interface TemplateData {
  user_id: number;
  above_building: string;
  name_building: string;
  below_building: string;
  area: number;        // Заменяем BigInteger на number
  bedroom: number;     // Заменяем BigInteger на number
  floor: number;       // Заменяем BigInteger на number
  restroom: string;    // Заменяем на string
  price: number;
  sales_price: number;
  path: string[];      // Заменяем List на string[]
}

const RedSide1: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<TemplateData | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try 
        const response = await axios.get('link to get', {
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }  
        });
        setData(response.data);
        console.log(response.data)
      } catch (error: unknown) {
          // Приведение error к типу, который можно использовать
          if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
              // Если это ошибка axios
              if (error.response) {
                  console.log('Ошибка от сервера:', error.response);
                  setError(`Ошибка: ${error.response.status} - ${error.response.data}`);
              } else if (error.request) {
                  console.log('Проблема с запросом:', error.request);
                  setError('Ошибка: Сервер не ответил. Проверьте соединение.');
              } else {
                  console.log('Ошибка при настройке запроса:', error.message);
                  setError(`Ошибка: ${error.message}`);
              }
          } else {
              // Если ошибка не связана с axios
              console.log('Неизвестная ошибка:', error);
              setError('Произошла неизвестная ошибка.');
          }
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>No data available</div>;

  /// other code///

fast_api_server/src/main.py



from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddlewarefrom some_features.router import my_router

app = FastAPI(
    title="Image Generation"
)

origins = [

    # here are localhost and //127.0.0.1:5173 and //127.0.0.1:3000
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH", "PUT"],
    allow_headers=["Content-Type", "Set-Cookie", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credential", "Authorization", "AxiosHeaders"],
)

app.include_router(some_router)

I can provide more code. Also if I have other errors in code generation could you point them out?
I changed CORS and configured cookies, tried to get in react server a certain user by telegram_id from the database, but in this case it was necessary to pass id there somehow. So I stopped on the option of storing the token in the session cookie. But this causes a 403 error.
Get request works if I send it in the same session as post request in my telegram bot, but it doesn't work in react. Could you help me out?

Please have a look at this answer.

This, as well as this and this might help as well.

JWTBearer() trying to find your token in Authorization header, and this is not happening as you are storing your token in cookies, and performing the validation right in your function, so error happens because there are no Authorization header and that's ok, as you using cookies.
You could remove dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())] and that should work fine.
Also, you should correctly populate values in origins (I can see that code is currently commented out)

Thank you so much for your help, but now there is another problem access_token is not showing up on http://localhost:3000 in F12/Application/Cookie, even though the same get request works in my tg bot. What am i doing wrong?
origins = [
"http://localhost:5173",
"http://127.0.0.1:5173",
"http://localhost:3000",
"http://127.0.0.1:3000",
]

Maybe the cause for the problem is that Cookies cannot be sent to different domains?

Yes, ensure that server and client are both at localhost or 127.0.0.1.
Also, you could try to add http:// at origins: `origins = ["http://localhost:5173"...]
